# Access Python Wrapper from ASP Classic

Tags: python, iis, asp-classic

I have written a python wrapper for a c dll.

I now wish to interact with this wrapper from an ASP classic script, served online via IIS7.

How would you recommend I do this?

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant to your particular case but you can actually use Python as the scripting language in classic asp,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276494

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Python wrapper, you need Python to use it. You can use Python as a scripting language from ASP, I recommend activestate's Python distribution, because it integrates with Windows and IIS by default.

You should be able to write an ASP page in Python and load your library in it.
[Here is more info](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/ASP_and_Python.html) on using Python from ASP.

It should even be possible to write a page in VBscript and call a piece of Python code in a Python WSC (Windows Scripting Component). [I have researched this a great deal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879788/how-to-debug-python-inside-a-wsc), it works, but if you want to do this you can only pass simple data types from one language to the other (strings, booleans, numbers)